# Accessing a Javascript variable inside an HTML file

Tags: javascript

I'm doing a little bit of reverse engineering on the Rapportive API in Gmail.

I make this request

```
import requests
url ='https://api.linkedin.com/uas/js/xdrpc.html'
r = requests.get(url)
print r.text
```

The response is an empty HTML file that has a lot of Javascript in it. On line 3661, it sets the RequestHeader for the subsequent call to Rapportive:

```
ak.setRequestHeader("oauth_token", ae);
```

Is there a way I can request that page and then return `ae`?

Comment: The only thing in the file is JS, or there is JS mixed inside an HTML body?

Comment: Only JS. You can actually run that code and see the response. The Rapportive API is really flexible.

Comment: You need to execute all the Javascript, because that's what sets `ae`.

Comment: I thought by running the page, it runs the javascript and sets the oauth header? How can I intercept it?

Comment: Seems this token is in cookie. You need to know what is token format. Try the cookie key value: `lihc_auth_str`

Comment: @MorganAllen You're not running the page, you're just downloading the Javascript code. The Javascript is run by the browser after it downloads it.

Comment: `requests.get()` is not a Javascript interpreter, it just performs the HTTP request to download the contents of the file.

Comment: @Barmr ahh ok, how do I run the code? There's requests.Session() that will persist session data. I was hoping to be able to do a .get() call and run the page to set the the token to the headers, but not sure how to run the initial file that I call inside Session()

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try:

1. Get the page as you already does;
2. Remove all non-javascript elements from the response page;
3. Prepend a javascript (described below) in the page's javascript to override some code;
4. Execute it with `eval('<code>')`;
5. Check if the token has been set correctly;

I'm proposing the following code to override the `XMLHttpRequest`.`setRequestHeader` functionality to be able to get the token:

```
// this will keep the token
var headerToken; 

// create a backup method
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.setRequestHeaderBkp = 
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.setRequestHeader; 

// override the "setRequestHeader" method
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.setRequestHeader = function(key, val)
{
  if ('oauth_token' === key)
    headerToken = val;

  this.setRequestHeaderBkp(key, val);
}
```

Comment: I'll give this a try!

Comment: @MorganAllen any news about the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you are just interested in retrieving the token can't you just do a regex match:

```
var str = '<script>var a = 1;...ak.setRequestHeader("oauth_token", ae);...</script>';
var token = str.match(/setRequestHeader\("oauth_token",\s*([^)]+)/)[1];
```

Although this assumes ae is the actual string value. If it's a variable this approach wouldn't work as easily.

Edit: If it's a variable you could do something like:

```
str.replace(/\w+\.setRequestHeader\([^,]+,\s*([^)]+)\s*\);/, 'oauthToken = \1';
```

Before running the JavaScript returned from the page, then the global `oauthToken` (notice the missing 'var') will contain the value of the token, assuming the the evaluation of the code is run in the same scope as the caller.

Comment: Well, I'm hoping to be able to request the page, parse it somehow and access token.

Comment: You are extracting simple string `ae` from response text. What it is necessary, it's `ae` value in javascript context. Imagine: `var ae = "foo";  ak.setRequestHeader("oauth_token", ae);`. You code will extract `ae` string, not `foo` value.

Comment: @Valijon in my edit we are replacing the statement `ak.setRequestHeader("oauth_token", ae);` with `oauthToken = ae;`. Therefore after the code has been run, the global variable we just declared should in theory contain ae's value.

Comment: I'm lost. We are speaking different things. Try to adapt your code to python syntax and check if you are right. Because, I don't see how are you going to get `ae` value from string...